# Which parameters can be used to differentiate between bulge and bulgeless galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies

I started doing a project which needs a set of [bulge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulge_%28astronomy%29)less galaxies, but I don't how to differentiate between bulge and bulgeless galaxy.

It would be useful if you could specify which parameters can be used for collecting the data.